# Can't connect on remote Redis with hostname when bind on IpV6

Tags: redis, ipv6

I have a remote redis server (named `billy.home`) configured and opened on IpV6 interface (the following line is in it's redis.conf file) :

```
bind ::
```

I can correctly connect from another server with its IP address :

```
pi@octo:~ $ host billy.home
billy.home has address 192.168.1.59
billy.home has IPv6 address 2a01:cb14:7e1:f100:6506:b877:d743:f29e
pi@octo:~ $ redis-cli    -h 2a01:cb14:7e1:f100:6506:b877:d743:f29e
[2a01:cb14:7e1:f100:6506:b877:d743:f29e]:6379>
```

However, I cannot connect with it's hostname

```
pi@octo:~ $ redis-cli -h billy.home
Could not connect to Redis at billy.home:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

I guess that's because redis tries to connect on IPv4 interface by default. If I change the redis configuration to

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

Then I can connect.

Is there a way to connect by hostname using IpV6 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Redis source code (deps/hiredis/net.c):

```c
static int _redisContextConnectTcp() {

    /* DNS lookup. To use dual stack, set both flags to prefer both IPv4 and
     * IPv6. By default, for historical reasons, we try IPv4 first and then we
     * try IPv6 only if no IPv4 address was found. */

}
```

As far as I can see in `redis-cli.c` or `deps/hiredis/hiredis.c`, there is nothing that *would* set "both" flags before calling this function. (That is, the functionality is available for *other* tools that use hiredis – it's specifically redis-cli that does not know how to use it.) The result is that hiredis does an IPv4-only DNS query first, which **succeeds,** so hiredis never tries an IPv6 nor combined query.

The only ways to make it work are therefore to a) make your Redis server listen on both IPv4 *and* IPv6; or b) create an IPv6-only DNS entry; or c) use a custom patched version of redis-cli (or hiredis, I guess).

On option a): Use `bind 0.0.0.0 ::` to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6. (It seems Redis disables the "`bind ::` listens on both" Linux magic.)

On option b): If your servers are spread out across different networks such that there's no IPv4 reachability, and if you're using some other security mechanism (let's say IPsec or at least a basic firewall), then it is *still* not a good idea to have "private" IP addresses in your DNS records – you don't want each connection attempt to start with the 'wrong' IPv4 address and potentially go somewhere else entirely.

In short, if the communications are IPv6-only, then have an IPv6-only DNS entry for them.

(Ideally, your database servers should not be accessible over the public Internet. If your servers are indeed spread out across different networks, then I'd recommend having the servers communicate over some kind of VPN tunnel (such as WireGuard). And once you have that VPN tunnel, you can have the servers communicate over IPv4 through the tunnel even if they're not directly IPv4-reachable over Internet.)